# the maximum size of an ostringstream buffer in cpp

Tags: c++, file-io

I want to ask a question about string streams as part of file I/O in CPP.

I am a beginner in C++ and have been learning about fileI/O.

Consider the code below *which works*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

std::cout << "Data validation!" << std::endl;
int value {};
std::string entry {};
bool done = false;

do {
    std::cout << "Please enter an integer: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> entry;
    std::istringstream validator {entry};
    if (validator >> value)
        done = true;
    else
        std::cout << "Sorry, that's not an integer" << std::endl;
    // discards the input buffer
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n'); // ignore everything up until the new line
    } while (!done);

    std::cout << "You entered the integer " << value << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

Here, I am attempting to validate whether a user's input (as a string) can be inserted into an integer variable, named `value`.

The code makes sense, except for the line:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
```

This is my interpretation of the above line:

`cin.ignore` will take two parameters, the first being the maximum number of characters to extract and discard, and the second being a delimiter.

The delimiter here is `\n` so all the characters up until `\n` are ignored.

When the user enters `13 Hello`, the `13` is extracted and inserted into `value`. The remainder of the string stream `Hello` is evaluated for its size.

The `std::numeric_limits::max()` function, which returns in this case an integer of type `std::streamsize` evaluates the maximum size of the stream after the extraction to `value` and then supplies this as the first argument of the `cin.ignore()` call.

*Am I mistaken? How does this code actually work logically?*

and out of interest, why are there angular brackets in `<std::streamsize>`? **(I've discovered they're templates for C++, which I will cover another time, so this is a solved question.)**

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I just watched a video on my own and discovered this topic is next in my series! Many thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

The angle brackets are needed because [`std:::numeric_limits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) is a [template class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates).  There are different *specializations* of `numeric_limits` for all of the various numeric/arithmetic data types.

[`std::basic_istream::ignore()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) has special handling for `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` specifically.  That particular value tells `ignore()` to read *endlessly* until the specified delimiter is reached, regardless of how many characters it takes to get there.  Any other numeric value tells `ignore()` to stop reading if that many characters have been read before the delimiter is reached.